# How to use Contains in LINQ using C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am having some collection of **HierarchyNodeEntity** values and collection of **Ancestors**.
Now I want to get the values from **theAncestors** by using the value of **db.HierarchyNodeEntities**.

Here I am using **Contains** to achieve this. But its not working. I want to use this **Contains** as **Like** operator in SQL. Can anyone tell me how can i use Like in this LINQ .

Thanks in Advance.

Here is code:

```
var q = from p in db.HierarchyNodeEntities                         
                      where theAncestors.Contains(p.HierarchyNodeEntity)
                      group p by p.PropertyKey
                         into prop
                         select
                             prop.OrderByDescending(p => p.LevelId).
                             FirstOrDefault();


     var list = q.ToList();
```

Comment: Can you define "its not working"? Do you get an exception or unexpected results etc.?

Comment: I am getting "0" value in my collection but the collection containing HierarchyNodeEntity.

Answer (score 2):

SuryaKavitha,

It may or may not work by passing in an object to compare as the sql won't understand which fields you are referring to. You may have to try something like:

**[Edit]**

```
theAncestors
    .Where(x => x.myproperty.Contains(p.HierarchyNodeEntity.anotherproperty))
```

this is my initial suggestion (you can also substitute `Contains` for `StartsWith` or `EndsWith`). Yopu may even be able to work with a straight equality check, i.e.:

```
theAncestors
    .Where(x => x.myproperty == p.HierarchyNodeEntity.anotherproperty)
```

Comment: theAncestors is a List. So I am not able to get the myproperty directly that means i am not able to check with each item of theAncestors becuase its List. Can you please tell me how can i get a single item from the List theAncestors in Where condition

Comment: oops -2nd edit, forgot to remove the `theAncestors.myproperty` part :-)

Comment: Thanks for your nice code. I'll check it and let you know. Thank you yar :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you want `like '%abc%'` sql notation.
You need to convert you values to `string` type first and only then use contains. Because `IEnumberable.Contains` differs.

```
theAncestors.Count(x => x.ToString().Contains(p.ToString())) > 0
```

Comment: But the theAncestors type is List only its not IEnumurable collection

Comment: @SuryaKavitha IEnumerable<x> extends List<x>, add the extension methods.. (`using System.Linq;`)